# Classifying a range of numbers as either prime or composite

Tags: python, primes, composite

Write source code that classifies all numbers from 2 to 20 as being either a composite number or a prime number.

I am only able to do a code where it's only one number not a range of numbers

```
num=2
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, int(num/2)+1):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num,"is a composite number")
        break
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
```

Comment: Please add code which you created to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet below:

```py
prime = [x for x in range(2, 21) if not [y for y in range(2, x) if x % y == 0]]
```